# getAddressesHtmlSelect() method rewrite

Tags: shipping-address

I am trying to rewrite this method. I was following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783185/getaddresseshtmlselect-change-magento. But unseccessfully.

code:

```
<blocks>
  <checkout>
    <rewrite>
      <onepage_billing>Namespace_Module_Block_Onepage_Billing</onepage_billing>
    </rewrite>
    <rewrite>
      <onepage_shipping>Namespace_Module_Block_Onepage_Shipping</onepage_shipping>
    </rewrite>
  </checkout>
</blocks>
```

and shipping(billing) class:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 */
class Namespace_Module_Block_Onepage_Shipping extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping
{

  public function getAddressesHtmlSelect($type)
  {

    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
          $options = array();
          foreach ($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses() as $address) {
              $options[] = array(
                  'value' => $address->getId(),
                  'label' => $address->format('oneline')
              );
          }

          $addressId = $this->getAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();
          if (empty($addressId)) {
              if ($type=='billing') {
                  $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
              } else {
                  $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
              }
              if ($address) {
                  $addressId = $address->getId();
              }
          }

          if ($type === 'shipping') {
            # code...
            $addressId = 5;
          }

          $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
              ->setName($type.'_address_id')
              ->setId($type.'-address-select')
              ->setClass('address-select')
              ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
              ->setValue($addressId)
              ->setOptions($options);

          $select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));

          return $select->getHtml();
      }
      return '';
  }
}

 ?>
```

What I'am doing wrong? Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm... you are defining `rewrite` tag twice

Change your **config.xml** like this

```
<blocks>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <onepage_billing>Namespace_Module_Block_Onepage_Billing</onepage_billing>
            <onepage_shipping>Namespace_Module_Block_Onepage_Shipping</onepage_shipping>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```